# Web api 2 string route failing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to use the web api in c# so far its been working pretty well but i just have a route that doesn't want to work and i searched a bit around for people with similar problems but their solution didn't seem to work.
I'm trying to have a specific route and capturing an email address in the string, here is my Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/contact")]
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    [Route("list/{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ContactList GetList(int id)
    {
        BasicAuthenticationIdentity identity = (BasicAuthenticationIdentity)this.User.Identity;
        ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel(identity.accountId);
        return (contactModel.GetList(id));
    }

    [Route("list/{id:int}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostList(int id)
    {
        BasicAuthenticationIdentity identity = (BasicAuthenticationIdentity)this.User.Identity;
        // To be implemented
    }

    [Route("attribute/{contactKey}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<ContactData> GetContactAttributeKey(string contactKey)
    {
        BasicAuthenticationIdentity identity = (BasicAuthenticationIdentity)this.User.Identity;
        ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel(identity.accountId);
        return (contactModel.GetContactAttribute(contactKey));
    }
}
```

The list route works well but when i try something like 
http://localhost/api/contact/attribute/test@test.com i keep getting HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found because it seems it can't find the route.
Is there something wrong in this?

I also have this in the webconfig

```
// Itinéraires de l'API Web
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I tried to see if other routes could be set that are the same but there is no other, i just have an account and segment route other than that, if anyone got some suggestion i'm open to everything right now :/

Comment: What happens if you pass a string value without '@'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `%40` instead of `@` symbol and `%2E` instead of `.`.

http://localhost/api/contact/attribute/test%40test%2Ecom

This is called [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), some characters are not valid in URL.

Comment: I tried that before but i just did it again by removing the '.' of the test.com making it like test%40testcom and now it works but with the test%40test.com it doesn't work. I'll try to check why but afaik this isn't suppose to be encoded as a character right?

Answer (score 1):

Okay its a comibnation of the answer of dotctor (using the url encode) and also there is a need to enable this in your web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```